# How can I pull a segment of the current page URL (last five digits) into an iFrame within the page, in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Our website uses Wordpress, and we pull our job openings from the software using an iFrame.  The iFrame query requires us to get the job "code" from the URL (e.g. `xyz.com/job-details/jobcode=11568`).

The vendor has provided javascript that is supposed to do this, but it does not work.  When the page loads the src just outputs as src(unknown)".  The iframe should read as `src="https://evoportalus.tracker-rms.com/COMPANY/jobs?fields=title,location&filters=Reference|<<the jobcode pulled from the URL>>`

Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
loadSite();
</script>

<iframe src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="700" height="700" id="trmsjobs"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var getQueryString = function (field, url) {
        var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
        var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
        var string = reg.exec(href);
        return string ? string[1] : null;
    };
    function loadSite() {
        var site = "https://evoportalus.tracker-rms.com/LincolnStrategic/jobs";
        site += "?fields=title,location&filters=reference|" + getQueryString("jobcode");
        document.getElementById('trmsjobs').src = site;
    }
</script>
```

**On Edit**

Apologies, I don't think my original explanation was clear enough.  The getQueryString variable seems to work; it outputs just fine.  The issue is that the "site" variable is not being inserted into the SRC value in the iFrame, which is what this script is supposed to do.

Comment: If the actual URL really is of the form `xyz.com/job-details/jobcode=11568`, then it does not have a query string part to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak your code to move the function call into the same block and change `var functionName = function` syntax to `function functionName` syntax

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="700" height="700" id="trmsjobs"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
        loadSite();
    function getQueryString (field, url) {
        var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
        var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
        var string = reg.exec(href);
        return string ? string[1] : null;
    };
    function loadSite() {
        var site = "https://evoportalus.tracker-rms.com/LincolnStrategic/jobs";
        site += "?fields=title,location&filters=reference|" + getQueryString("jobcode");
        console.log(site);
        document.getElementById('trmsjobs').src = site;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Adding this to the function just outputs the job code in the log, but I've already confirmed that the function gets the job code correctly.  The issue I'm stuck with is that the src="" in the iframe is blank, when it should be populated by the site var being generated by the function.

Comment: @JosephKrengel sorry about that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, with the other changes you recommended it's now pulling correctly.  I had to make some further changes to the site variable because the vendor apparently didn't bother proofreading their documentation, but I could never have done that without the function passing the SRC to the iframe.  Thank you!

Comment: This solution worked for me too. A follow up question -- this website also uses the TrackerRMS system. But they are adding their own form to filter the job results. (https://travelplacement.com/open-jobs/). How are the values from the drop-down fields passed to the first iframe, to update/filter the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with "/", then look for each component for the parameter you want, splitting this time with "=". Not a clean solution, but works:

```
var getQueryString = function(field, url){
    var ret=null;
    url.split("/").forEach(function(v){
        var s=v.split("=");
        if(s.length>1 && s[0]==field){
            ret=s[1];
            return;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```